# Conflicting information about second derivative test and graphing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When performing a first derivative test, you have a point where the first derivative is $0$ or undefined.  If the values to the left of that point are increasing and those to the right are decreasing, that means this point is a local maximum for the function, right?

But for the values to the left, on the point itself, and to the right, the second derivative is positive.  So if we look only at the first derivative, we have a local maximum.  But my textbook says that "If $f''(c) > 0$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $(c, f(c))$."  This happens when $f'(c) = 0$, which it does here.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here but this seems to be contradictory.  If you consider only the first derivative test, you get a max, but if you include the second derivative test, you get a minimum.  Here's the information in bullet form:

- $x$ on $(-5, -1)$: $f'(x)$ is positive, $f''(x)$ is positive
- $x$ in $-1$:  $f'(x) = 0$,         $f''(x)$ is positive
- $x$ on $(-1, 2)$: $f'(x)$ is negative, $f''(x)$ is positive

Comment: This can't happen. Are you sure the function is differentiable at $-1$?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is differentiable, actually.  If it were not would that make more sense?  I was not given any function, only this data, and am trying to construct a possible function for it.  What do you mean by it can't happen?

Comment: There is no function that satisfies those constraints. If the second derivative is positive the first derivative can't change sign from positive to negative since the second derivative being positive means the first derivative is increasing.

Comment: This can happen only if $f'$ is discontinuous in $-1$.

Comment: The only way the function could behave like you say on intervals $(-5,-1)$ and $(-1,2)$ would be if the function was not differentiable at $-1$ and had a cusp there. Note: This also means the second derivative doesn't exist at $-1$ of course.

Comment: Yep, that's what had me going nuts! It must be an error in the problem, or perhaps it is discontinuous.  But what about the first derivative suggesting a local max and the second derivative suggesting a local minimum?  That could be applied to any function, not just this one.  Is it conflicting or am I just nuts?

Comment: Nope. If the first derivative suggest a local max at $a$ then if the function is twice differentiable at $a$ the second derivative will be either negative or $0$. Of course the function might not be differentiable at $a$ even once in which case the second derivative won't tell you anything since it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is the function a military secret so you can't show it here?

Comment: There is no given function for the problem.  It would make things a lot easier if it was given though!